# Failing Maven build on Flex project http://repository.sonatype.org:80: No route to host

Tags: maven, apache-flex, sonatype, flexmojos

A Maven build on a Flex project recently stopped working even though there has been no changes to the code. The build fails with the following error:

`Sep 08, 2016 12:00:21 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when processing request to {}->http://repository.sonatype.org:80: No route to host`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use https://repository.sonatype.org now, the server is no longer available over plain http.

Comment: That may be the case but the repository URL is beyond my control as it's part of the Flexmojos plugin. If it has been moved to HTTPS only then it seems a bit silly that a redirect wasn't setup.

Comment: We have added a redirect from http to https for repository.sonatype.org.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that version 7.0.1 of the `flexmojos-maven-plugin` has a reference somewhere to [repository.sonatype.org](http://repository.sonatype.org) which has recently gone offline (September 7th 2016) and this causes the build to fail due to the unresolved dependency.

I have updated to version 7.1.0 of the plugin which seems to  have resolved the issue as it no longer tried to use this location.